# Net Reactor License Invalidation & Reactivation Tool

Tags: c#, winforms, net-reactor

I am using .Net Reactor for the first time, I have downloaded the trial version, and I need help with Invalidation and Reactivation tools, let me explain.

1. I Generated the Invalidation.exe by going to License Invalidation Tool when I ran it for the first time it worked, (as I was testing it worked correctly) I deleted all the files and created a new Net Reactor project (to test again) and protected the same app again Now when I created another invalidation.exe it returns the confirmation code which is valid in License Invalidation Tool but my app still works. I have tried like 20 times but every time my app is still working. Now I have created a button inside my application to Invalidate the license and it works correctly every time. My question is why did Invalidation.exe stop working?
2. I have unchecked the Run without license file checkbox as I assumed if I checked this checkbox I have to manually check and validate the license file by using license.dll which I want to leave to Net Reactor, so if now I Invalidate the license How should I use Reactivation code generated from Reactivation tool, as my application won't even restart, I know I can Protect the app using new master key, but is there any other way?